# Create a list which contains two columns New and Date in sharepoint programmatically

Tags: list, web-part

Want to create a list in sharepoint which contains NEWS and DATE programmatically.

so please help me and provide me the code for it.

Comment: what you need here.have you created a list or do you want to create a list also programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to add list in sharepoint programmatically.

```
public void createList()
{
    // choose your site
    SPSite site = new SPSite("http://merdev-moss:5050");
    SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
    // create new Generic list called "My List"
    lists.Add("My List", "My list Description", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);

    SPList newList = web.Lists["My List"];
    // create Text type new column called "My Column"
    newList.Fields.Add("My Column", SPFieldType.Text, true);
    /*create lookup type new column called "Lookup Column"
    * Here I am going to get the information from the "Title"
    * column of a list called "User Roles"
    */
    SPList targetList = web.Lists["User Roles"];
    newList.Fields.AddLookup("Lookup Column", targetList.ID, false);
    SPFieldLookup lkp = (SPFieldLookup)newList.Fields["Lookup Column"];
    lkp.LookupField = targetList.Fields["Title"].InternalName;
    lkp.Update();
    // make new column visible in default view
    SPView view = newList.DefaultView;
    view.ViewFields.Add("My Column");
    view.ViewFields.Add("Lookup Column");
    view.Update();
}
```